# ERROR: invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

If i just run the leaflet part. it gives an ouput but in the shiny app it is giving the above error.

When i try removing the code from addCircleMarkers it gives an out put without any marker. There is something wrong in that particular statement i am guessing.

Also, I want to change the marker shape in leaflet for each of the type but that is again something not available from the resources i am finding over the internet. It shows that i have to manually find links (i will need almost 10 to do that)

```
data('zipcode')


#removing the extra empty column
data$X <- NULL

#cleaning the zipcodes
data$ZIP.CODE <- clean.zipcodes(data$ZIP.CODE)

#adding the Stage2/Stage1 column
combine$ratio <- combine$Stage2/combine$Stage1
combine <- merge(data, zipcode,  by.x='ZIP.CODE', by.y='zip')
combine[is.na(combine)] <- 0


ui<-fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('rank','Ziprank',choices=levels(combine$ZIP.RANK),multiple=T,selected = 'A'),
      selectInput('type','Ziptype',choices=levels(combine$TYPE),multiple=T,selected = 'PUBLIC'),
      selectInput('market','Market',choices=c(1,2,3,4),multiple=T,selected = 1),
      selectInput('housevalue','Median Housing Value',choices=levels(combine$MEDIAN.HOUSING.VALUE),multiple=T,selected = '1HVL'),
      selectInput('familyincome','Median Family Value',choices=levels(combine$MEDIAN.FAMILY.INCOME),multiple=T,selected = '1MFI'),
      selectInput('buyingpower','Median House Buying Power',choices=levels(combine$MEDIAN.HOUSE.BUYING.POWER),multiple=T,selected = '1MHB'),
      selectInput('ethnicity','Ethnicity',choices=levels(combine$ETHNICITY),multiple=T,selected = '1ETH'),
      selectInput('population','Population Density',choices=levels(combine$POPULATION.DENSITY),multiple=T,selected = '1POP'),
      selectInput('masters','Masters Degree',choices=levels(combine$MASTERS.DEGREE),multiple=T,selected = '1MDG'),
      selectInput('associate','Associate Degree',choices=levels(combine$ASSOCIATES.DEGREE),multiple=T,selected = '1ADG'),
      selectInput('highschool','High School Age Population',choices=levels(combine$HIGH.SCHOOL.AGE.POPULATION),multiple=T,selected = '1HSP'),
      selectInput('epscode','EPS code',choices=levels(combine$EPS.CODE),multiple=T,selected = 'MS01'),
      selectInput('state','State',choices=unique(combine$state),multiple=T,selected = 'NY'),
      sliderInput('score','Zipscore', min(combine$ZIP.SCORE), max(combine$ZIP.SCORE), value=c(0.1,0.3))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput('plot')
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <-renderLeaflet({
    final <- subset(combine, ZIP.RANK %in% input$rank &
                    TYPE %in% input$type &
                    MARKET %in% input$market &
                    MEDIAN.HOUSING.VALUE  %in% input$housevalue &
                    MEDIAN.FAMILY.INCOME %in% input$familyincome &
                    MEDIAN.HOUSE.BUYING.POWER %in% input$buyingpower &
                    ETHNICITY %in% input$ethnicity &
                    POPULATION.DENSITY %in% input$population & 
                    MASTERS.DEGREE %in% input$masters &
                    ASSOCIATES.DEGREE %in% input$associate & 
                    HIGH.SCHOOL.AGE.POPULATION %in% input$highschool &
                    EPS.CODE  %in% input$epscode &
                    state %in% input$state &
                    ZIP.SCORE >= input$score[1] & ZIP.SCORE <= input$score[2]
                    )
    pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "Reds", domain = c(0:1))
    p <- final %>%
      leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles('CartoDB') %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = final, color = ~pal(ZIP.SCORE),label=~GEONAME) %>%
      addLegend(title = "ZipScore", pal = pal, values = c(0:1), 
                position = "bottomright")
    p
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your circle markers via `leafletProxy()`. In my opinion you should rewrite your code in the following way. Put your `pal` statement outside above your ui. Wrap all your data subsetting which you reference with `final` in its own `reactive({})` function. Then you can add your `leaflet()` in the base call `output$Plot`. You can than update the user input with its own observer via `observe()` and refernce the user input with leaflets own update function `leafletProxy()`

```
pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "Reds", domain = c(0:1))
server <- function(input, output) {

final <- reactive({
data_subset <- subset(combine, ZIP.RANK %in% input$rank &
                        TYPE %in% input$type &
                        MARKET %in% input$market &
                        MEDIAN.HOUSING.VALUE  %in% input$housevalue &
                        MEDIAN.FAMILY.INCOME %in% input$familyincome &
                        MEDIAN.HOUSE.BUYING.POWER %in% input$buyingpower &
                        ETHNICITY %in% input$ethnicity &
                        POPULATION.DENSITY %in% input$population & 
                        MASTERS.DEGREE %in% input$masters &
                        ASSOCIATES.DEGREE %in% input$associate & 
                        HIGH.SCHOOL.AGE.POPULATION %in% input$highschool &
                        EPS.CODE  %in% input$epscode &
                        state %in% input$state &
                        ZIP.SCORE >= input$score[1] & ZIP.SCORE <=   input$score[2])
 })


  })
 output$plot <-renderLeaflet({
  leaflet(data = combine) %>% 
  addProviderTiles('CartoDB')
})

observe({
leafletProxy("plot", data = final() %>%
               addCircleMarkers(color = ~pal(final()$ZIP.SCORE),     label=~final()$GEONAME) %>%
               addLegend(title = "ZipScore", pal = pal, values = c(0:1), 
                         position = "bottomright")

 })
}
```

Comment: The app keeps crashing as soon as I run it. I updated my r and my packages but it still wouldnt run. Now the error is  [No stack trace available]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce your example: Don't know where you are taking the "zipcode" data from and also couldn't find clean.zipcodes()
(Package "zipcode" might be the origin, but is not on CRAN anymore...)

However, I ran into a similar problem and that's what I found out so far:
It looks like leaflet is havinhg difficulties when you provide an empty list to the "label" argument in e.g. addCircleMarkers. This inherently happens, when your dataset is empty (0 rows).

I managed to work around this issue by forcing a type conversion using paste0(...,'').

In your case it would be:

```
p <- final %>%
  leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles('CartoDB') %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = final, 
                   color = ~pal(ZIP.SCORE),
                   label = ~paste0(GEONAME, '')))
```

Probably, there is more elegant ways to do it, but at least it worked for me.